# Obtener id de INSERT mediante un CallableStatement

Tags: java, mysql

he creado un procedimiento almacenado en mi base de datos SQL. La problemática que tengo es que quiero conocer el ID (AUTO_INCREMENT, PK) de la fila recién creada.

El código es:

JAVA

```
try (
            Connection conn = sql.conectarMySQL();
            CallableStatement sentencia = (CallableStatement) conn.prepareCall("{call newIds(?)}");
        ){  
            sentencia.setInt(1, 2);
            sentencia.execute();
// Aquí deseo recoger el ID creado para poder almacenarlo
...
}
```

SQL

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE newIds(IN modos_id INT(11))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tbl_ids (modosid)
    VALUES (modos_id);
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faltan varias cosas en tu código:

- Definir en la SP el parámetro de salida, que será el valor del último ID.
- Luego del INSERT ejecutar una consulta que te devuelva el último ID. Aquí asumimos que la columna ID de la tabla es auto-incremental y usaremos `LAST_INSERT_ID()` para obtenerlo. Si no es así, deberás ejecutar otro tipo de consulta, ordenando descendente y usando LIMIT 1.
- Registrar en el `CallableStatement` el parámetro de salida, [como explica el tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/connector-j-5.1-en/connector-j-usagenotes-statements-callable.html) en el ejemplo 6.5

Haciendo esas correcciones, tu código quedaría así:

### SQL

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE newIds(IN modos_id INT(11), OUT last_id INT)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tbl_ids (modosid)
    VALUES (modos_id);
    SET last_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END;
```

### Java

Como bien indica [el tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/connector-j-5.1-en/connector-j-usagenotes-statements-callable.htmlhttps://), los pasos para este caso son los siguientes:

1. Preparar la consulta, **poniendo un marcador también para el parámetro de salida**.
2. Registrar los parámetros de salida cuando los haya, como es el caso aquí.
3. Pasar los parámetros de entrada cuando los haya.
4. Recoger el parámetro de salida, por su índice o por su nombre.

Aplicando estos cuatro pasos en su orden, tenemos:

```
try (
            Connection conn = sql.conectarMySQL();
            // OJO: Dos marcadores ?, ?
            CallableStatement sentencia = (CallableStatement) conn.prepareCall("{call newIds(?, ?)}");
        ){ 
            //Registramos parámetro de salida
            //Se puede registrar por nombre también
            sentencia.registerOutParameter(2, Types.INTEGER); 
            //Pasamos el parámetro de entrada
            sentencia.setInt(1, 2);
            sentencia.execute();
// Aquí deseo recoger el ID creado para poder almacenarlo
            //Recogemos el parámetro de salida, por el índice
            int lastID = sentencia.getInt(2); // index-based
            //O bien por el nombre
            //Decídete por uno de los dos, no uses ambos   
            int lastID = sentencia.getInt("last_id"); // name-based         
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, era justo lo que necesitaba! Una pregunta que se surge en base a tu respuesta: la forma name-based se puede usar para registrar los parámetros de entrada?

Comment: @lRetro me alegro de que te haya servido. Puedes pasar también parámetros de entrada usando el nombre, [ver **Ejemplo 6.6** en el tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/connector-j-5.1-en/connector-j-usagenotes-statements-callable.html)